# Xamarin.Forms WebView not rendering position:fixed css correctly?

Tags: android, css, mono, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to build a cross-platform app in Xamarin using Xamarin Forms that just views my site.
Most of the stuff is working really well, but I've come across a big problem under Android. I made a test Xamarin app not using Xamarin Forms, just the native Android stuff Xamarin offers, to test if its just a Forms issue. Turns out it seems to be...

The issue seems to be that the Xamarin Forms WebView is rendering the css for “position:fixed” VERY incorrectly, while under the “native” Xamarin Andoid app everything is rendered as would be expected.

Now as far as I understood, Xamarin Forms should use the same underlying html renderer as the “native” app’s html renderer, which I imagined to be Chromium under Android 4.4 and above.

Is this not the case? Perhaps this is a known bug? Or just a setup issue on my side?

*Below are images illustrating the bug. As you can see, the big blue bar is not rendered correctly on the right.*

[image]

This is the test HTML the apps are rendering to illustrate the bug:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background: blue; height:100px; width: 100%; position:fixed; left: 0; top: 0;">
        <div style="margin:0 auto; width: 200px;">
            <p style="color: white;">HELLO WORLD</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any help on this would be **GREATLY** appreciated!
Thanks,
Bas

Comment: facing the same issue. got it fixed?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in a html . Add height on a WebView or put it in Grid row.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/